# Apache Zeppelin user with read permission cannot access notebook, insufficient privileges to write note

Tags: permissions

I am running apache zeppelin 0.8 with Shiro's default authentication. I have created a notebook "A" with admin user which successfully connects to my DB, runs the job and outputs the corresponding chart. I have changed the notebook view to reporting mode and have added user1 to readers inside the permissions modal. when I log in as user1, I can open notebook "A" but Zeppelin prompts, saying the user1 has "insufficient privileges to write a note".
I have tried various combinations of user roles and permissions but only the ones as "writer" can open the note. is it not possible to access a note as a non-writer user?

Comment: Which version do you use? v0.8.0 or v0.8.1??
I think it's a bug in 0.8.x version. it works for v0.7.3.
Why don't you try to running zeppelin v0.7.3

Comment: @stevepark good to know it works in earlier versions. sure thing! I'll try out 0.7.3 and let you know whether It works.

Comment: This is a bug: [2680](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2680)